# Absolute conditional minimum of function in n-dimensional space

Tags: calculus

Function

$$F(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

on the constraint

$$G(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i-1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality of arithmetic and geometric means says:

$(x_1x_2....x_n)^{1/n} \le \frac{F(x_1,...,x_n)}{n}$.

If $x_1x_2....x_n=1$, then we get

$n=F(1,...,1) \le F(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: thank you so much, Fred!